# how to get reference of an object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a game and came to a point where I had nothing in my mind. want to take reference of an object by collider frequently. I don't know how to make so please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately it is absolutely unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve and where you are struggling. Could you spread more light on how your code looks like and where exactly the problem is / what exactly you are asking? Please also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Take Object A with script As and script 2As and collider Ac
Object B with script Bs and collider Ac

Their might be 3 different things you are looking to achieve here:

**Reference Script Bs from script As:**
First you need to reference the Game Object that Bs is on (B) from script As
At the very top of script As you would add:

```
public GameObject objectB;
```

Then later in your code when you want to reference the script on objectB you can do:

```
int value = objectB.GetComponent<Bs>().score;
```

Where score is a variable in Bs

**Reference Script 2As from As:**
In this case we already are on the same gameobject so we can simply do

```
int value = gameObject.GetComponent<2As>().Score;
```

Where Score is a integer in the Script 2As
The reason we can just say gameObject.GetComponent here instead  of having to reference the other object is because gameObject with a lower case g refers the object that the script is sitting on. So effectively we just say "get the other script on this gameobject"

Lastly (I think you are trying to do this maybe?)
**Take a collider and get the GameObject on this collider then get the script on that GameObject:**

```
public Collider coll;
int val = coll.GameObject.GetComponent<script>().value;|
```

I hope that helps, I didn't really understand your question so if this doesn't answer your question let me know :)

Also join my discord if you have any other questions: discord.io/gamedev

Answer (score -1):

We really need more info about what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to know what an object collided with recently? trying to raycast? Depending on what you want to do with it, you might need to reference different components on the gameobject. etc.

But here's an example:

```
//Component on a gameobject with a collider attached.
public class RefByCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] //makes it show in inspector
    private GameObject lastCollisionGO;

    //Called everytime this gameobject collides with another that has a collider (non trigger)
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        lastCollisionGO = other.gameObject; //replaces reference with the newly collided object.
    }
}
```

This component on a gameobject with a collider attached will replace the reference stored in lastCollisionGO everytime the object collides with another object.

Note: If you try to query the value of lastCollisionGO before it collides with something, it will be empty and give you a null reference exception.